# How to include a header file in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, header-files, preprocessor

`/***You willl find good information in the answer selected and comments of post by @datell*****/`

`/**** Also there is something related to use off "modules" and "inline before template" (i am asking on template classes and not template functions, both are different) in c++, that if its related, i cant relate in reality(i am a noob)*****/`

i am asking how can i include a header file in my main.cpp, i have implemented basic stack operations in it ; main.cpp btack.h and btack.cpp.
Compiler is giving a long list of linkage errors(works fine if i give declaration and defination in btack.h, ofcourse i dont want to do that for modularity).
its a temmplate class. i will provide the code which runs, that is without btack.cpp

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "btack.h"
int main() {
    char a;
    int z;
    //std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    btack <int> b(3);
    btack <char> c(3);
    b.push(4);
    b.push(5);
```

btack.h

```
#ifndef btack_h
#define btack_h
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename s> class btack
{
    int TOS,size;
    s *ptr;
public:
    btack(int );
    ~btack();
    void push(s ob);
    s pop();

};

template <typename s> btack<s>::btack(int i)
{
    ptr = (s*)malloc(i*sizeof(s));
    TOS=0;
    size=i;
}

template <typename s> void btack<s>::push(s ob)
{
    if(TOS>=size)
    {
        cout<<"stack is full"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    ptr[TOS]=ob;
    TOS++;
}

template <typename s> s btack<s>::pop()
{
    if(TOS<=0)
    {
        cout<<"stack is empty"<<endl;
        return ((s) 0);
    }
    TOS--;
    return ptr[TOS];
}
template <typename s> btack<s>::~btack()
{free(ptr);}

#endif /* btack_h */
```

so basically i was going through so many internet posts and i found that you have to use "Export" keyword, but that word is no longer used, i was unable to find a proper guide on this topic. NEw c++ standards please.
A guide how i can learn this thing from scratch.
Please you mighty coders, a guiding link will help.

Update********
For all those saying about explicitly declaring data types at end of header:
suppose it is a STL implementation of stack.h, you dont instantiate explicitly the various types of data types you want to use, it automatically do that

---

points of worth:

C++14 does not really permit abstract templates... In some sense, they need to be "concrete" (implemented in header files) – Basile Starynkevitch

Comment: How do you build your project? Show us a precise command

Comment: g++ main.cpp is enough, because you dont compile .h files

Comment: when i used btack.cpp i did g++ btack.cpp main.cpp

Comment: ask me if you want more specifications

Comment: What exact compilation commands have you run? What actual diagnostics did you get? Please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: @RichardCritten    i have read that post, the solution that you want to state here that is :

Comment: "Another solution is to keep the implementation separated, and explicitly instantiate all the template instances" -----------is a bad solutionn as may be i will be using object of a class defined by me, this will hurt the portability of header file

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch  the commands: g++ btack.cpp main.cpp (where i get linkage errors) , and where i dont have a seprate btack.cpp i do :g++ main.cpp  (it works well)

Comment: I think you didn't really get the meaning of *explicitly instantiate all the template instances*. Please read about it here: [How do I explicitly instantiate a template function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933056/how-do-i-explicitly-instantiate-a-template-function/4933205#4933205)

Comment: @LohitakshTrehan: please **edit your question**, don't add comments here.

Comment: i get it , but suppose it is a STL implementation of stack.h, you dont instantiate explicitly the various types of data types you want to use, it automatically do that @datell

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch sorry, noob mistake

Comment: As an aside, `using namespace std` in a header is a bit of a bad smell, any other module which includes your header will automagically be using namespace std, and could lead to name conflicts or incorrect functionality.

Comment: it was a small implementation, otherwise i would have use "std::" instead, thanks for pointing out @Colin__s

Comment: Instead of mentioning my answer in your question (which is very uncommon) you can upvote or accept it. See [Somone answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for further information.

Comment: comments are good, no answer, and i will aceept it, about upvote(i dont have a reputation, but i will click anyways ) @datell , hope you upvote my question too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, a C++14 compiler needs to know for every aggregate type (in particular *instantiated* template classes) its size, alignment, [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) (if any) and sequence of fields -with their type and alignment-.

Hence, templates are *practically* not abstract types, even if programmers should view them that way.

Therefore, standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) headers (like `<vector>`, `<map>` etc...) are generally including a lot of *internal* stuff defining the *internal implementation* of the template, and all the template member functions are inlined.

In practice, a standard header like `<vector>` is expanded to a lot of stuff (about ten thousand lines of C++ on my GCC 6 compiler on Linux).

Try the following command (it is preprocessing) with a simple file `mytest.cc` having `#include <vector>`:

```
 g++ -C -E -H -Wall mytest.cc > mytest.ii
```

The `-H` option shows all the internal included files. The `-C -E` is asking for preprocessed form with comments into `mytest.ii`. Then look with an editor (or a pager) into the generated `mytest.ii`; it would be quite big.

And that is why C++ compilation is often slow.

Modules are a future feature of C++ which could help. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34652029/841108).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a template class you don't need any .cpp file for an implementation of it.

So you got two files: `main.cpp` and `btack.h`. Main contains `#include "btack.h"`.

You compile it with `g++ main.cpp`.

Comment: wont that harm the basic idea of abstractness i.e. seprating code and declaration.

Comment: C++14 does not really permit abstract templates... In some sense, they need to be "concrete" (implemented in header files)

Comment: @datell: Wrong advice: should be compiled with `g++ -Wall -g main.cpp` since both `-Wall`(for all warnings) & `-g` (for debug info) are needed

Comment: The reason for this is the usage of templates. Imagine it like this: If you would separate your `btack.h` into `back.h` (containing signatures) and `btack.cpp` (containing implementations) and you would compile everything the compiler would try to compile `btack.cpp` without knowlege of `main.cpp`. What shoudl he do with the generic type `T`? He don't now how it is going to used concretly in `main.cpp`. Therefore the header must either contain the template implementationen or you explicitly instantiate all the template instances.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch so there is no way out?

Comment: @datell you said right about diferent compilations, i read that yesterday

Comment: @LohitakshTrehan: no, there is no practical way in C++14 .... Look into the source code of `<set>` in practice, or compile some file using standard C++ containers with `g++ -C -E -H` to get the preprocessed form, then study it... Look into module proposal for future C++ standards.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I gave him a small working example not an advice for final build or testing rules. But you are right, one should always use at least some additional compiler flags.

Comment: Thanks @datell   i will study some more, because i really need to know about these compiler flags

Comment: Thanks @BasileStarynkevitch   i will study some more, because i really need to know about these compiler flag

Answer (score 0):

three separated files

`btack.cpp` with the cpp code for btack
`btack.h` the header file
`main.cpp`

in `main.cpp` ; on first line just write

```
 #include "btack.h"
```

if btack is in the same directory; if it's not, write the path of the file

then compile `main.cpp` and `btack.cpp` (don't forget to also 
`#include "btack.h"` in `btack.cpp`)

Comment: no its not working, i am using a template class. its giving errors, previously it was some "export" keyword, but new c++ has deleted its use

Comment: i can compile your code on ubuntu 16.10 with g++ 6.2 @LohitakshTrehan

Comment: i gave you the code which was compiling i.e. both declaration and defination in .h file, if you seprate the defination in btack.cpp file, then it gives linking error

Answer (score 0):

```
// stack node structure
struct Node {
    char data;
    struct Node* next;
};
struct Node* initiStack(void);
int isEmpty(struct Node** top);
// push function
void push(struct Node** top, int data);

// pop function
int pop(struct Node** top);
int peek(struct Node** top_re);
int size(char expn[]);
```